Migrating from Arduino to Raspberry Pi with ROS2
I am currently working on a project involving an Arduino Rev 4 WiFi to develop a robot capable of carrying belongings and following a user. Despite being in the early stages, we have successfully managed to establish wireless communication with our mobile app, allowing us to control the robot's movement via basic button commands.
However, we have realized that implementing machine learning for user-following, computer vision, and object detection will necessitate more processing power than the Arduino can provide. Consequently, I have been tasked with migrating our code to a more robust platform, specifically a Raspberry Pi running ROS2 Foxy.
I have explored potential solutions, including rosserial_arduino, but it is only compatible with ROS1 and not with our current setup using ROS2 Foxy on a Raspberry Pi 3B. Additionally, I attempted to use micro_ROS, but encountered compatibility issues with our Arduino board.
Given my limited experience with ROS2, I am seeking guidance on the best approach to achieve this migration efficiently. Any advice, resources, or suggestions on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your assistance.
Best regards,
New Note: Due to foxy being discontinued and the amount of RAM the later versions of ROS2 require we will be upgrading our Raspberry pi 3B with 1GB of RAM to a 4B with 4GB of RAM which will allow us to use the jazzy version of ROS2.

what is your specific question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I polished my question a bit, I rambled in the beginning because I was not sure what to ask myself. So I did a bit of research in what I necessarily want, and tried different solutions to my problem. I realized that the main problem was the ROS2 version that I was using with the Pi that I currently have.
